# Can you update core data without deleting objects and then adding them again? - ios

Tags: ios, objective-c, core-data

Is there a way to update existing core data on the app from mysql instead of deleting the objects and then adding them again?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The usual approach is to fetch the existing objects and update their values with new data from your server. To do that, you need to have a unique ID that's included in the server call and that you save in Core Data. Then you do something like this, for each entry:

1. Get the unique ID returned by your server.
2. Fetch the managed object from Core Data that has the same unique ID.
3. Update the managed object properties from the incoming server data.
4. Save changes.